# RegEx IIS ReWrite .asp to Extensionless

Tags: regex, iis

I am trying to get a supposedly simple RegEx to work in IIS using web.config but without success. I'm not very familiar with ReGex. What I need to do is permanently redirect this;

www.domainname.com/news/feature-name.asp

To this:

www.domainname.com/news/feature-name/

The code I have currently is as follows:

```
<rule name="new_style_news_redirect" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^news/([^/]+).asp?$" />
<action type="Redirect" edirectType="Permanent" url="http://www.domainname.com/news/{R:0}/" />
</rule>
```

But this isn't working. It generates the following URL:

```
http://www.domainname.com/news/news/feature-name.asp/
```

Can anybody tell me where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `1` instead of `0`

```
<match url="^news/([^/]+)[.]asp?$" />
<action type="Redirect" edirectType="Permanent" url="http://www.domainname.com/news/{R:1}/" />
                                                                                       ^
```

Comment: Aaargh. I should have spotted that. Thanks you're a star :)

Comment: someone doing serial downvoting.. Note that 0 represent the match and 1 represents the first capturing group.